# Traceback (most recent call last): IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'demo.docx'

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word, notepad++, python-docx

I'm a beginner in Python.
I saw a post online saying that the following four lines can make a new docx document.
I followed the instructions and installed the python-docx module. I put the code in the Notepad++, and got such result (see the image). What is wrong with the code? Or do I miss something in Python? Many many thanks!

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
document.add_paragraph('Hello,Word!')
document.save('demo.docx')
```

If finally the bug is eliminated, where should be, following the four-line code, the new file located? This actually bothers me a lot. Thank you for your help.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\new
> 1.txt", line 4, in <module> document.save('demo.docx') File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 142, in save
> self._part.save(path_or_stream) File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\parts\document.py", line 129, in
> save self.package.save(path_or_stream) File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 160, in save
> PackageWriter.write(pkg_file, self.rels, self.parts) File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\pkgwriter.py", line 32, in
> write phys_writer = PhysPkgWriter(pkg_file) File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 141, in
> __init__ self._zipf = ZipFile(pkg_file, 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__ self.fp =
> open(file, modeDict[mode]) IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> 'demo.docx'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You never set a current directory in your program, so it uses the default, which isn't somewhere that you have write permission to. Specify an absolute path to demo.docx or change the directory to somewhere like your Documents folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I specify an absolute path to demo.docx?

Comment: Should I write something like, in line 4, document.save('C:\Users\Admin\Python\demo.docx')? Thanks

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes, but otherwise, that will work.